# Fetch timestamped counts from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, count, timestamp

I have a table of nodes:

```
nid type  created   status
2   blog  134292319 1
3   forum 134292536 1
4   blog  135921392 0
```

To graph the number of published (status=1) nodes over time, I execute this query:

```
SELECT created, type
FROM node WHERE status = 1
ORDER BY created
```

I then go through this data set in PHP, splitting it into timestamped groups with a node count associated with each group. The results are cached, so slow execution isn't a problem.

I also have a table of comments:

```
nid timestamp status
2   134292363 1
3   134293234 1
```

I want to incorporate *forum* comment counts into the graph of node counts.

To get the comment counts, I would run this query:

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM comments
INNER JOIN node ON comments.nid = node.nid
WHERE
  node.type = 'forum'
  AND comments.status = 1
ORDER BY timestamp
```

I need to somehow combine these two queries, to end up with (for the examples given):

```
created   type
134292319 blog
134292536 forum
134293234 forum_comment
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by forum comment **Counts** .  Your example output doesn't show counts.

Comment: Also, is the output supposed to be ordered only by `timestamp`/ (`created`)?

Comment: Yes, the output is supposed to be ordered by created date. The MySQL isn't supposed to output counts as such; it is the PHP that turns the actual results into counts. Ie. it goes through the result set, and every time the timestamp reaches a certain value it increments the "group" - otherwise adding one to the current group's count.

Comment: And then the counts, associated with their respective timestamps, are stored in a cache table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you your example output but I am not sure it's exactly what you are looking for based on your description of the question.

```
SELECT created, type FROM
(
   SELECT created, type
   FROM node WHERE status = 1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT timestamp as created, 'forum_comment' as type
   FROM comments
   INNER JOIN node ON comments.nid = node.nid
   WHERE node.type = 'forum'
     AND comments.status = 1
) AS U
ORDER BY U.created
```

Comment: That is in fact exactly what I was looking for. Never heard of the UNION ALL before. Cheers :D